# Check who delete files via SSH

Tags: shell, ssh

How I can check who delete file in some directory via ssh(if I have the root)? 
Maybe I check who exactly run command to delete ?
 Or who log in now on the server?

Comment: There are many users logged in. I want to know who exactly delete files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `who` command will tell you users that are currently logged in.

Regarding viewing the history of other users, [this answer might help you](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31723/can-i-search-bash-history-across-all-users-on-a-server). Specifically the command below (if the user is using a bash shell).

```
grep -e "$pattern" /home/*/.bash_history
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to activate audit on your server.

Audit provides a utility that allows you to filter the audit reports for certain events of interest. You can filter for:

- User
- Group
- Audit ID
- Remote Hostname
- Remote Host Address
- System Call
- System Call Arguments
- File
- **File Operations <= You are here**
- Success or Failure

Check the doc : [AUDIT DOC FOR LINUX](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sled11/singlehtml/audit_quickstart/audit_quickstart.html)